# CodeSandbox code is not the same as the code when deployed to netlify

Tags: html, css, reactjs, netlify, codesandbox

In the CodeSandox live preview this is what happens when I hover over my Instagram div element:
[CodeSandbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytvZN.png)

In netlify this happens:  [actual website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jqth.png)

I am wanting my website to actually look like my CodeSandbox result does anyone have any ideas as to why this happens?

Code for Instagram div:

```
.ds5:hover {
  border: double 4px transparent;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-width: 1;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(44,44,44), rgba(44,44,44)), 
  linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(81,91,212,1) 0%, rgba(129,52,175,1) 17%, rgba(221,42,123,1) 43%, rgba(254,218,119,1) 74%, rgba(245,133,41,1) 100%);

  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
}
.ds5:hover::after {
  border: solid 4px rgba(221, 42, 123, 1)

}
```

Comment: Hi. You need to provide some code to determine the exact problem.

Comment: Do you want my css for the div?

Comment: Yes that would be helpful

Comment: Ok I added the code